# Using Git for Data History

Tags: sql, database, oracle, git

I am currently tracking history of changes across multiple tables in an Oracle database. We are storing the entire row that changes in a separate table with the same columns as the data table, except that we also have columns for

- date/time
- user
- version number (auto-incremented and shared by all tables)

I currently have no way of displaying this data for regular users who have no access to the database, and we have been reconsidering the whole history system for the following reasons:

- Completely duplicate data structure
- Need to store history info in every row that changes
- Difficult to track discrete change-sets across tables
- Difficult to view history at particular time
- No efficient conflict detection

Therefore, I have been considering using Git to track the history. I would envision the following components

- File system representation of tables (see example below)
- One official repository that writes to the database on fast-forward update

  - This repository will be the only user that can modify the data tables.
- Abort any update that causes database errors so that we can still have database-level data enforcement
- File structure will be exactly mapped to the tables so that databse modification can be automatic
- Local repository pools for each application

  - Attempt push
  - If fails for non-fast-forward; rebase
  - If rebase fails due to conflicts; abort
- Write entire repository nightly to enforce Git history as single source of truth

Has anyone attempted anything similar? If so, are there any details that I should know about.

Additionally, are there any libraries or tools available that are geared to this sort of thing?

Are there better ways of doing something like this with pure Oracle SQL that can solve all my issues?

**Example file structure:**
(D) indicates Directory; (F) indicates File; Quoted string is file contents

- Schema_USER (D)

  - Table_ITEM (D)

    - Row_ITEM_ID-24435- (D)

      - Column_ITEM_ID (F) : "24435"
      - Column_DESCRIPTION (F) : "Big Ball"
    - Row_ITEM_ID-24436- (D)

      - Column_ITEM_ID (F) : "24436"
      - Column_DESCRIPTION : "Small Ball"
  - Table_CATEGORY (D)

    - Row_CATEGORY_ID-35- (D)

      - Column_CATEGORY_ID (F) : "35"
      - Column_NAME (F) : "Balls"
  - Table_ITEM_CATEGORY (D)

    - Row_CATEGORY_ID-35-ITEM_ID-24436 (D)

      - Column_CATEGORY_ID (F) : "35"
      - Column_ITEM_ID (F) : "24436"

Comment: That sounds like a horrible hacks, sorry. Fix your real problem: add the needed reporting tools, and add a changeset number where it matters in your tables. If you need ti generate snapshots at specific times, Oracle has features for that too (Total Recall it was called at some point, and compression options to live with that).

Comment: "I currently have no way of displaying this data for regular users who have no access to the database"  Fnord.  What sort of regular users have no access to the database?  Why not just build them a screen which shows the change history?

Comment: @Mat I have considered Total Recall, but it will not solve tracking application users' changes, messages, and distinct changesets, all of which are built in with Git. Total Recall will also not prevent conurrent modifications of the same data.